# What does "suitable offerings" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "suitable offerings" mean in the sentence below? Does it mean the offerings which are **fit** to be offered to God or the offerings that man **must** give to God?

> **Suitable offerings** for the altar of 'the Lord thy God' include 'the firstlings of thy flocks, and of choice of thy fields, and of the chief of all holy things'. These animal offerings must be firstborn and perfect and, if from the flock, should 'divide the hoof and chew the cud'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because the meaning is probably clear from the larger context, which is not given here.  If it isn't try http://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ab2 any religion can have a God. OP is discussing the phrasing of the language used not it's theological content. Why close?

Comment: @StevieV  I, myself, wouldn't try to interpret a short sample of religious text. I read your answer, and your logic wrt to English is impeccable (+1), but religious phrasing has many quirks

Comment: @ab2 thank you for your compliment, but I am just an enthusiast :) The way I look at it, it's our job here on this site to shed light on things in the context of the language, regardless of the substance.

Answer (score 3):

OK first take a look at...

> or the offerings that man must give to God

We know that it cannot be this, because *offerings* are simply *offerings* and not something one *must* provide. While there may be some consequences for *not* making the offering, it is still not *required*. According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offering), an *offering* is only contributive in nature.

Now let's consider...

> are fit to be offered to God

Let's think about some of the things that are said in the cited paragraph. The paragraph talks about...

> the altar of 'the Lord thy God' include 'the firstlings of thy flocks, and of choice of thy fields, and of the chief of all holy things

So what we have here is a list of *offerings* if you will. This list is intended for who? God, as opposed to man. So, we are thereby giving a list followed by this description...

> These animal offerings must be firstborn and perfect and, if from the flock, should 'divide the hoof and chew the cud

In these above two excerpts we are giving a list followed by a description of the *offerings*. This implies that we are justifying what *should be fit for God*. So, I'll take choice two:

**The excerpt is describing offerings that are fit for God.**